# Javascript Image Slider - How to keep moving on mouse hover

Tags: javascript

I found a javascript image slider here: https://codepen.io/EricPorter/pen/XaOEpP and wanted to use it for my project.

I narrowed down the script to what I wanted below. It's exactly what I am looking to do except one thing. It pauses on mouse hover.

I have tried a few different things, but I cannot figure out how to keep the script sliding on mouse hover. I am somewhat limited in JS, I typically use vendor scripts and adjust as needed, if you could give a solution and explain the piece that is pausing it on mouse hover, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

```
! function(o) {
    "use strict";
    o.fn.sliderResponsive = function(i) {
        var n, e = o.extend({
                slidePause: 4e3,
                fadeSpeed: 600,
                autoPlay: "on",
                showArrows: "on",
                hideDots: "on",
                hoverZoom: "off",
                titleBarTop: "off"
            }, i),
            d = o(this),
            s = d.find("> div").length,
            t = 0;

        function f() {
            n = setInterval(function() {
                l()
            }, e.slidePause)
        }

        function l() {
            (t = d.find(".show").index() + 1) > s - 1 && (t = 0), a()
        }

        function a() {
            d.find(".show").removeClass("show").fadeOut(), d.find("> div").eq(t).fadeIn(e.fadeSpeed).addClass("show"), d.find("> ul").find(".showli").removeClass("showli"), d.find("> ul > li").eq(t).addClass("showli")
        }
        return d.append("<ul></ul>"), d.find("> div").each(function() {
            d.find("> ul").append("<li></li>")
        }), d.find("div:first-of-type").addClass("show"), d.find("li:first-of-type").addClass("showli"), d.find("> div").not(".show").fadeOut(), "on" === e.autoPlay && f(), "on" === e.showArrows && d.addClass("showArrows"), "on" === e.hideDots && d.addClass("hideDots"), "off" === e.hoverZoom && d.addClass("hoverZoomOff"), "on" === e.titleBarTop && d.addClass("titleBarTop"), d.mouseover(function() {
            "on" === e.autoPlay && clearInterval(n)
        }), d.mouseout(function() {
            "on" === e.autoPlay && f()
        }), d.find("> .right").click(l), d.find("> .left").click(function() {
            (t = d.find(".show").index() - 1) < 0 && (t = s - 1);
            a()
        }), d.find(" > ul > li").click(function() {
            t = o(this).index(), a(o(this).index())
        }), d
    }
}(jQuery), $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider3").sliderResponsive({
        hoverZoom: "on"
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi madeofquartz, if an answer on this page solved you problem please consider marking it as accepted for other users that might encounter the same problem. Thanks

Comment: This did not solve my problem, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Well then you have errors somewhere else in your code, because it works perfectly on the fiddle. I'll make one right now and share

Comment: https://codepen.io/testing-12345/pen/JjYXbPb

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new property to the settings object like below and then check for if the new property is set to on or off in the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` functions.

**Note:** check the three comments in the code below

```js
! function(o) {
    "use strict";
    o.fn.sliderResponsive = function(i) {
        var n, e = o.extend({
                slidePause: 4e3,
                fadeSpeed: 600,
                autoPlay: "on",
                showArrows: "on",
                hideDots: "on",
                hoverZoom: "off",
                titleBarTop: "off",
                hoverStopPlay: "off"   // <-- Add new property
            }, i),
            d = o(this),
            s = d.find("> div").length,
            t = 0;

        function f() {
            n = setInterval(function() {
                l()
            }, e.slidePause)
        }

        function l() {
            (t = d.find(".show").index() + 1) > s - 1 && (t = 0), a()
        }

        function a() {
            d.find(".show").removeClass("show").fadeOut(), d.find("> div").eq(t).fadeIn(e.fadeSpeed).addClass("show"), d.find("> ul").find(".showli").removeClass("showli"), d.find("> ul > li").eq(t).addClass("showli")
        }
        return d.append("<ul></ul>"), d.find("> div").each(function() {
            d.find("> ul").append("<li></li>")
        }), d.find("div:first-of-type").addClass("show"), d.find("li:first-of-type").addClass("showli"), d.find("> div").not(".show").fadeOut(), "on" === e.autoPlay && f(), "on" === e.showArrows && d.addClass("showArrows"), "on" === e.hideDots && d.addClass("hideDots"), "off" === e.hoverZoom && d.addClass("hoverZoomOff"), "on" === e.titleBarTop && d.addClass("titleBarTop"), d.mouseover(function() {
            if("on" === e.autoPlay && e.hoverStopPlay === "on") { // <-- Add new condition
                clearInterval(n);
            }
        }), d.mouseout(function() {
            if("on" === e.autoPlay && e.hoverStopPlay === "on") { // <-- Add new condition
                f();
            }
        }), d.find("> .right").click(l), d.find("> .left").click(function() {
            (t = d.find(".show").index() - 1) < 0 && (t = s - 1);
            a()
        }), d.find(" > ul > li").click(function() {
            t = o(this).index(), a(o(this).index())
        }), d
    }
}(jQuery), $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider3").sliderResponsive({
        hoverZoom: "on"
    })
});
```